# 8vCPU vs Octacore process?

Tags: cpu, amazon-ec2, cpu-speed, quad-core

Is 8vCPU same as Octa core processor ? For example at [Amazon Servers](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)  I see 8 vCPU against c4.2xlarge. Is it a quad core
processor ?

**So is one virtual CPU is equivalent to  1 core?**

**Update:-** Sorry i wrote quad core instead of octa core in my initial post. Update to Octa core now

Comment: Yes, but how did you arrive at the conclusion a quadcore is backing it? I very much doubt Amazon is selling hyperthreaded cores.

Comment: are you saying each cpu in 8vCPU is a quad core processor  or 8vCPU  is equivalent to quadcore processor ?

Comment: @user3198603 - Daniel is saying they are not using CPUs with Hyperthreading.  "So is one virtual CPU is equivalent to 1 core?" - For the purposes of Amazons equipment, *Yes*, it is. **Worth pointing out, that a virtual CPU is not Hyperthreading even on a physical machine**

Comment: @Ramhound As you said from `For the purposes of Amazons equipment one virtual CPU is equivalent to 1 core`. it means Is 8vCPU is equivalent to  quad core processor ?

Comment: @DanielB Sorry did not get your question when you say `how did you arrive at the conclusion a quadcore is backing it` ?  I believe from amazon equipment perspective,  1 vCPU is equivalent to 1 core. So  My interpretation for `8vCPU` is 8vCPU is equivalent to 8 core processor. Hence it same as quad core processor ?

Comment: Quad core is 4 not 8....why are you just repeating if everything is a quad core? 8 is octacore...

Comment: @Ramhound I am extremely sorry in my post/comments i wrote quadcore instead of octacore. So last time i want to confirm is that `Is 8vCPU is equivalent to octa core processor`  from amazon equipment perspective ?

Comment: Yes;  I literally just said that.